# Reloading Page using javascript but updating original body HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to reload a page in javascript but update the original HTML defined in the body tag? An example is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){  
        document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.body.innerHTML = `<h1> ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999)}`;
        location.reload()
    });
    }
</script>
<body>
    <h1>Hehe</h1>
    <button id = "button">Reset</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The above will change the original body tag to a random number when "button" is clicked on and as expected, the body tag will revert back to its original state after refreshing (though it will briefly show the updated state before refreshing).

Is it possible to have the body html remain different even after "refresh" is called?

Comment: You want to reload the page but keep its value generated?, try using **localStorage**. If you reload the page, it will lose its values.

Comment: You can show the value generated for a period of time before reloading the page, using a **setTimeout()**. But after reload if you dont store the values, you will lose the values though.

Comment: Thank for for you reply @ElvisPimentel. I followed your suggestion and it now works as expected!